# Is there a way to create a certain number of new lines depending on what number a user inputs?

Tags: python, input

Today is my second day with python and coding in general, and I wanted to create a code that makes a certain number of lines depending on the number that the user inputs. For example, if I was asking the user how many pets they have and then ask what the names of each pet, can I create a new line asking what the name of each pet is depending on the number they said? So if they say that they have 3 pets, the program automatically makes 3 more lines to ask what the name of each pet is?

I haven't been able to do previous codes or programs because I don't know everything you can do with python yet and how to do it.

Comment: Use a [`for`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for) loop over the `input()` statement and storage to capture this data

Comment: what is a "line"?  And, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You might find `lists` useful.

```
number_of_pets = int(input("Enter how many pets you have: "))
```

You might get the number, and then create a `for loop` to add them together.
First you need an empty list to work with:

```
pets = []
```

Then you can start adding

```
for i in range(number_of_pets):
    pets.append(input(f"Enter the name of pet number {i + 1}: "))
```

And if you wish to print the pets, you can use similar loop, but this time, not taking input, but printing what's stored:

```
for i in range(number_of_pets):
    print(f"Pet number {i + 1}: {pets[i]}")
```